# Reducing height of multicol separator line

Tags: tables, rules, multicol

I am bodging a table using `multicol` and `rule` so that I can have cells of dynamic sizes and populate it using a macro rather than manually.

It mostly works, however I would like to reduce height of the line between the columns. 
See an example of how I am building this, and a picture of what the result of the full document looks like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=15mm, top=0.8cm, bottom=0.7cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,headsep=2pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt} \newline
\stepcounter{qnumber}
  Q\theqnumber. \textsf{#1}

  \vspace{4.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{intervention}
\thispagestyle{intervention}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
\section*{Week 1}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\question{Calculate the following:
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)] 
        \item $10 \times 0.5$
        \item $10 \times 0.25$
    \end{enumerate}  
}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Produces an output like:

[image]

How do I reduce this height?

Comment: Please try to make an MWE.  Your code references pagestyles and source files not found on other systems.

Comment: `\rule[1ex]{\columnwidth}{0.4pt}` ???? Note `[1ex]` and adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `tikz`.

I've created the macro `\mypagerule` with two arguments which represent, respectively, the distance (in cm) from the top and the bottom of the page.

You have to set it for every page, but from the image you posted, I think you have only one page.

Here's the code (I've modified something to make it compilable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,top=0.8cm, bottom=0.7cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,headsep=2pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{label={(\alph*)},leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\mypagerule}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw($(current page.north)-(0,#1)$)--($(current page.south)+(0,#2)$);% --
    \end{tikzpicture}
}   

\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
    \noindent
    \rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt} \newline
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
    Q\theqnumber.~\textsf{#1}
    \vspace{4.5mm}
}

\begin{document}
    \section*{Week 1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \question{Calculate the following:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $10 \times 0.5$
                \item $10 \times 0.25$
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
        \question{Calculate the following percentage:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $10$\% of $500$
                \item $5$\% of $500$
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
        \question{Round the following numerbers (I don't know the rest of the question):
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $10.456789789$
                \item $51.5454844$
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
        \question{The following question is about Standard Form:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Express $3600$ in standard form
                \item Write $2.1 \times {10}^{3}$ as a normal number
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
        \question{Mr Wilson and Mr Bedford have a peanlty shoot-out. The probability of Mr Wilson scoring is 0.4:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item What is the probability he misses?
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
        \question{Ten students take ten penalties each. The number that each of them scores is below:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $1$
                \item $2$
                \item $3$
                \item $4$
                \item $5$
                \item $6$
                \item $7$
                \item $8$
                \item $9$
                \item $10$
            \end{enumerate} 
        }
    \mypagerule{2}{6}
    \end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

Here's the output (the actual line is of the correct thickness, in the picture it seems thick but it is not):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inelegant solution, awaiting a better one.  It simply raises the `\rule`s defining each cell.  The commented out portion is a potential lead on a better solution...but I can't work it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

%\def\columnseprulecolor{%
%\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0.4\textheight][c]{\rule{0.4\textheight}{0.1pt}}}
%    }%

\section*{Section Title}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\noindent\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}
\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}
\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}
\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}
\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}
\raisebox{2.25ex}{\rule{\columnwidth}{0.01pt}}
Here is some content, in its own cell defined by the column separator rule and the rules above and below it.\vspace{5ex}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @commonhare - I can't accept this because it doesn't answer the question - I can build an MWE but not a full-on solution as this introduces other random problems to my setup - it's neat, though :)

Comment: Try that commented out section...I think there might be a way to pass the sum of the vertical dimensions of your cells to the `\columnseprulecolor` definition (maybe requiring two compiles)...?